# Suddenly no data can be written to SD Card from PC (MTP), read Ok, Galaxy Ace 4. What to do?

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, external-sd, file-transfer, mtp

It is not a filesystem error as I tried to install a different SD Card to see if it is possible to copy files to it, same behavior, can read, not write.

There are plenty of free space in SD card. 32 GB total, like 20 or more free.

The problem is reproducible in two operating systems, Windows XP SP3 (Desktop computer), Windows Vista 32 bits (Toshiba Laptop). Right now I don't have access to other systems.

I don't think that this is related to the problem of some apps not being able to write to SD Card. What I'm trying to do is copy files from Windows PC to Samsung Phone SD Card.

In PTP mode Win XP does not even display the content of the SD Card (this is known problem in XP). In MTP mode, It displays it, allows me to copy from phone to PC, but If I try to copy from PC to Phone, the copy stalls indefinitely and no single byte is copied, not even the file created.

In Win XP, Event Viewer shows this message:

```
Event ID: 15200

MTP USB Driver has cancelled the operation 0x9808
```

I didn't check Vista Event Viewer yet but I think the same event will appear.

I tried installing Samsung Kies and Samsung Smart Switch, as they install drivers, and then with Windows Explorer again, same situation.

I also Removed Avast from phone and disabled Avast in Win XP. Same result.

Comment: Can you try with Windows 7? Have you rebooted the phone before connecting it again?

Comment: I own a Win 7 desktop but I do not have access to it right now. I can try tomorrow or the day after tomorrow. I will update question with the result. And yes, I tried to reboot the phone.

Comment: Do you have a USB Mass storage mode? If you do, try using it.

Comment: USB pen drive works ok in either computer. USB hard drive works ok. The Ace 4 does not have mass storage as an option, only PTP and MTP. My old Speadtrum phone has mass storage by default and works ok, but I cannot use mass storage with the Ace 4, it would be perfect if I could.

Answer (score 4):

This might be a simple problem of a write protection or permissions issue. Take a backup of your SD card and format the SD card. This may reset the permissions and you will be able to write into the SD card

Comment: I tried to install another SD card to see if the same problem occurs. And yes, the same problem. So I don't think that will work. But I will try it anyway. I will update question if it works.

Comment: I had the same problem as yours and it worked like a charm for me

Answer (score 1):

The USB cable was defective in my case.

I turned off all the unnecessary USB ports but saw no change. When I changed USB cable and restarted the machine, the problem resolved.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like the Windows driver function timeout error. What you can try:

1. Open device manager.
2. Find your device under "portable devices"
3. Uninstall the device.
4. Reboot PC and reconnect the device.
5. Allow the device to install again and check if it works now.
6. If it doesn't, try installing the Google USB driver for the device.

Comment: This answer looks promising. Give me some time and I will try that. Also the Google USB driver.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this issue solved before by removing the phone from Windows device manager. Then use Add Hardware to bring it back, but don't let it automatically add it. Instead select Choose Device from List.  Then don't choose PTP or MTP, but chose USB mass storage device. I know your device does not have a mass storage mode, but this has worked on other similar devices.

Comment: Confirm that I understood correctly. You want me to remove the device from Device Manager on Windows. Then connect the phone and when windows is installing it, cancel, then choose manually a USB mass storage driver? Can such a thing be done?

Answer (score 0):

I have same problem with S3.
So far work perfelctly.I copy files to phone internal RAM without problem.

There was no change on the computer,only install splashtop streamer util.
And install apk to phone.(Possible infected exe and apk files?)

now:
Copy files from phone works.
Copy files to phone not works+ MTP connect crash,need reconnect the phone.
Copy little files 200kb to phone works.(2mb not works)...1xGb free

I reset the phone then works fine, one 1,6mb file copy completed then again came out the malfunkction.

but i not clear cache.
Possible android virus?